# MySQL multiple SELECT question

Tags: mysql

How can I add the following code example 1 to example 2 without messing up my query.

Example 1

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
INNER JOIN users_articles ON users.user_id = users_articles.user_id
WHERE users.active IS NULL
AND users.deletion = 0
```

Example 2

```
SELECT users.user_id, users_articles.user_id, users_articles.title, articles_comments.article_id, articles_comments.comment, articles_comments.comment_id
FROM users_articles
INNER JOIN articles_comments ON users_articles.id = articles_comments.article_id
INNER JOIN users ON articles_comments.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.active IS NULL
AND users.deletion = 0
ORDER BY articles_comments.date_created DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: what does "without messing up my query." mean?

Comment: I just dont want my query to display an error :)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I just want to know how can I add example 1 to example 2

Comment: Does either example give you an error, as written?  I don't understand what you're trying to do.  There's nothing in example 1 that Example 2 doesn't already do, other than returning all the columns in the join.

Comment: @Andrew Cooper I guess I want to know how to run another select in example 2?

Comment: Are you looking to take the results from example 1 AND example 2?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what you want to achieve by putting the queries together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but does this help?

```
SELECT users.user_id, users_articles.user_id, users_articles.title, articles_comments.article_id, articles_comments.comment, articles_comments.comment_id
FROM users_articles
  INNER JOIN articles_comments ON users_articles.id = articles_comments.article_id
  INNER JOIN users ON articles_comments.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.active IS NULL
  AND users.deletion = 0
ORDER BY articles_comments.date_created DESC
LIMIT 50
```

**Update**

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT users.user_id, users_articles.user_id, users_articles.title, articles_comments.article_id, articles_comments.comment, articles_comments.comment_id
FROM users_articles
  INNER JOIN articles_comments ON users_articles.id = articles_comments.article_id
  INNER JOIN users ON articles_comments.user_id = users.user_id
    AND users.active IS NULL
    AND users.deletion = 0
ORDER BY articles_comments.date_created DESC
LIMIT 50;
SELECT *
FROM users 
  INNER JOIN users_articles ON users.user_id = users_articles.user_id
WHERE users.active IS NULL
  AND users.deletion = 0
```

Comment: NO it's just the same as example 2.

Comment: What, exactly, do you want the combined query to do?

Comment: I just want to know how to add the first select from example 1 to example 2 so in other words how do I run another select?